# How to align button to stay beside text in a list

Tags: html, css, list, web, alignment

So I need to make a list and I need to know how do I add a custom button for li and align it to stay beside the text when my text is aligned to the centre.

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-image: url("button.png");
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>I am Caring and Helpful</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just `<ul>
    <li>I am Caring and Helpful<button>I am a button</button></li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding the buttons via `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/dfbvr/)

The structure of the HTML is simple. The `data-hover` attribute value will be the text of the button.

```
<ul>
    <li data-hover="button 1">Item</li>
    <li data-hover="button 2">Item</li>
    <li data-hover="button 3">Item</li>
    <li data-hover="other button">Item</li>
</ul>
```

A content value of `attr(data-hover)` will effectively add the `li` element's data attribute.

```
li:before {
    content:attr(data-hover);
}
```

Alternatively, another approach would just be to directly nest elements within the `li`. You could wrap an anchor element around a `button` element or a `span`. Here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vySj3/). This example is visually identical to the pseudo element solution, it just involves different semantics.

---

If all you are looking to do is align a `background-image` to the `li` elements, just use padding and the `background-position` shorthand to adjust it to the image accordingly. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/B2UAg/). I *wouldn't* add the image/button via `list-style-image`, as it has limited positioning.

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 60px;
    background: url("http://placehold.it/50x50") 0 0 / 50px 50px no-repeat;
}
```